# How to design loss layer when regressing age from image using caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, regression, caffe

I'm trying to reproduce following thesis with caffe

[Deep EXpectation](https://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/publications/papers/proceedings/eth_biwi_01229.pdf)

Last layer has 100 outputs, each layer is implying probability of predicted age. And final predicted age is calculated by following equation:

[image: Equation]

so I want to make loss using EUCLIDEAN_LOSS with label and Predicted value.

I show my prototxt for last output layer and loss layer.

```
layer {
    bottom: "pool5"
    top: "fc100"
    name: "fc100"
    type: "InnerProduct"
    inner_product_param {
        num_output: 100
    }
}

layer {
    bottom: "fc100"
    top: "prob"
    name: "prob"
    type: "Softmax"
}

layer {
    name: "loss"
    type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
    bottom: "fc100"
    bottom: "label"
    top: "loss"
    loss_weight: 1
}
```

Just for now, I am trying these with SoftmaxWithLoss. However, this loss is more appropriate to classification not for regression. How can I design the loss layer for in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**
I've been through similar task once, and from my experience there was little difference (in terms of output accuracy) between training discrete labels and regressing a single continuous value.

---

There are several ways you can approach this problem:

#### 1. Regressing a single output

Since you only need to predict a single scalar value, you should train your net to do just so:

```
layer {
    bottom: "pool5"
    top: "fc1"
    name: "fc1"
    type: "InnerProduct"
    inner_product_param {
        num_output: 1  # predict single output
    }
}
```

You need to make sure the predicted value is in range [0..99]:

```
layer {
  bottom: "fc1"
  top: "pred01"  # map to [0..1] range
  type: "Sigmoid"
  name: "pred01"
}
layer {
  bottom: "pred01"
  top: "pred_age"
  type: "Scale"
  name: "pred_age"
  param { lr_mult: 0 }  # do not learn this scale - it is fixed
  scale_param {
    bias_term: false
    filler { type: "constant" value: 99 }
  }
}
```

Once you have the prediction in `pred_age` you can add a loss layer

```
layer {
  bottom: "pred_age"
  bottom: "true_age"
  top: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"
  name: "loss"
}
```

Though, I would advice to use [`"SmoothL1"`](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/files/764206/SmoothL1Loss.1.pdf) in this case as it is more robust.

#### 2. Regressing the expectation of the discrete prediction

You can implement your prediction formula in caffe. You need a **fixed** vector of values [0..99] for that. There are many ways to do that, none is very straight-forward. Here's one way using [net-surgery](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb):

First, define the net

```
layer {
  bottom: "prob"
  top: "pred_age"
  name: "pred_age"
  type: "Convolution"
  param { lr_mult: 0 }  # fixed layer. 
  convolution_param { 
    num_output: 1
    bias_term: false
  }
}
layer {
  bottom: "pred_age"
  bottom: "true_age"
  top: "loss"
  type: "EuclideanLoss"  # same comment about type of loss as before
  name: "loss"
}
```

You cannot use this net yet, first you need to set the kernel of `pred_age` layer to 0..99.

In python, load the new

```
net = caffe.Net('path/to/train_val.prototxt', caffe.TRAIN)
li = list(net._layer_names).index('pred_age')  # get layer index
net.layers[li].blobs[0].data[...] = np.arange(100, dtype=np.float32)  # set the kernel
net.save('/path/to/init_weights.caffemodel')  # save the weights
```

Now you can train your net, but **MAKE SURE** you are starting your train from the weights saved in `'/path/to/init_weights.caffemodel'`.

Comment: I'm trying second way but I got error when building model from prototxt. "pred_age" layer giving error. The layer requires at least two params [num_output, kernel_size]. I used kernel_size as 100 but it also give me error....

Comment: @ilkyutonylee my bad kernel_size should be 1

Comment: I tried filter_size: 100 and 1 but it means square filter so it doesn't work
after that i need to use rectangle filter so i need to set [kernel_w, kernel_h].

Comment: Here is what I did.
layer {
 bottom: "prob"
 top: "prob2d"
 name: "prob2d"
 type: "Reshape"
 reshape_param {
  shape: {
   dim: 1
   dim: 1
   dim: 1
   dim: 100
  }
 }
}

layer {
  bottom: "prob2d"
  top: "pred_age"
  name: "pred_age"
  type: "Convolution"
  param { lr_mult: 0 }  # fixed layer.
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 1
  #kernel_size: 10
  kernel_w: 100
  kernel_h: 1
  bias_term: false
  }
}

I changed shape of prob forcely and apply 2d convolution.

Comment: Your answer was really helpful and you drive me to solve this issue. Truely appreciate!